# Docker cannot access host files using -v option

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

Not 100% sure this is the right place but let's try.

I'm using on my Windows laptop the Docker Quickstart Terminal (docker toolbox) to get access to a Linux env with Google AppEngine, python, mysql...

Well, that seems to work and when I type `docker run -i -t appengine /bin/bash` I get access to this env.

Now I'd like to have access to some of my local (host) files so I can edit them with my Windows editors but run them into the docker instance.

I've seen a `-v` option but cannot make it work.

What I do
`docker run -v /d/workspace:/home/root/workspace:rw -i -t appengine /bin/bash`

But `workspace` stays empty in the Docker instance...

Any help appreciated

(I've read this before to post: https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine#windows)

Comment: Did you try using a double slash before "d" (`//d/workspace`)? And is your drive D even reachable at your Quickstart terminal? Type `ls /` inside your Qucikstart Terminal to see if `/d` is available.

Comment: `ls /` does not show `/d` but I can go, from the terminal, to `/d/workspace`, type `pwd` and it shows `/d/workspace`. I tried with double slash with no luck.

Comment: and when you `cd` into `/d/workspace` (inside Quickstart terminal), then your files are available? Does the problem also occurs under path `/c/...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Shared Drives , you can follow this [Blog](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c)

Comment: He uses Docker Quickstart Terminal / Docker Toolbox, not Docker for Windows.